# Try[Future[Int]] behaves oddly

Tags: scala

Playing around with the Scala REPL, I discovered that `Try(Future(1))` prints out `Success(Future(Success(1)))` (see below screenshot). Is this just a REPL oddity? Where does the second Success come from?

[image: REPL printout]

Comment: Future returns Option[Try[..]]. Check this `val res: Option[Try[Int]] = Future(1).value`. So the second one is from value.

Comment: it can be in progress at time when you call `value`. So it returns `None` in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first Success comes from `Try` because it executed the code successfully.
The second Success comes from `Future` cause it resolved the code block passed to it successfully.